# Why is my second class not allowing me to call my methods from first class?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, methods

I am creating a code for a small game of 4 horses running a set distance across my terminal. I have it to where it is outputting my horses that I have added and my users horse, but when I go to my next class to build the race it self, I keep getting method undefined errors. I searched for something similar but couldn't find anything. learningruby.com has some roundabout answers to it, but not showing me what im missing. 
    class Horses

```
  @@list_of_horses = []

  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :position

  def initialize
    self.name = nil
    self.position = 0
  end

  def self.add_horse(*horse_variables)
    horse = Horses.new

    horse.name = horse_variables[0]

    @@list_of_horses.push horse
  end

  def self.add_user(*user_variables)
    add_user = Horses.new
    add_user.name = user_variables[0]

    @@list_of_horses.push add_user
  end


  def self.display_data
    puts "*" * 60
    @@list_of_horses.each do |racer|
        print "-" * racer.position
        puts racer.name
                           end
  end

  def move_forward
    self.position += rand(1..5)
  end


  def self.display_horses
    @@list_of_horses
  end
end


horse1 = Horses.add_horse ("Jackrabbit")
horse2 = Horses.add_horse ("Pokey")
horse3 = Horses.add_horse ("Snips")
user1 = Horses.add_user ("Jim")

Horses.display_data
```

Now when I run just this file, It will give me the printout in my terminal of

---

Jackrabbit

Pokey

Snips

Jim

But when I start trying to call the methods I have created in my Horses class in my next class of Race even outside of the Race class itself, Im returning method undefined.

```
require_relative 'Horses_class.rb'

no_winner = true

class Race 

      def begin_race
    puts "And the Race has begun!"
  end


end

while no_winner == true
puts begin_race
racing = Race.new
racing.Horses.display_data


end
```

So why am I not allowed to call my other methods? should I be using a splat or is there something more simplistic that im missing? Thank you in advanced.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

Your `begin_race` method seems to be out of scope when you're calling it. You need to use either the `.` or the `::` (scope) operator to access it.

```
class Race
    def self.begin_race
        puts "And the race has begun!"
    end
end

Race::begin_race
# or
Race.begin_race
```

Also, when you call `racing.Horses.display_data` you must make sure that your `Horses` class is a sub-class of you `racing` class. You can *not* call a sub-class via an object, you must call it through the class constant.

```
class Race
    class Horses
        def self.display_data
            puts "The Data"
        end
    end
end

# Access 'display_data'
Race::Horses.display_data
```

So in this case your `require_relative` should be *within* your `Race` class and your `while` block should look like

```
while no_winner == true
    Race.begin_race
    Race::Horses.display_data
end
```

Comment: That makes sense, but why is it that in my while loop I cannot call the other methods from Horses_class.rb?

Comment: It is because your class isn't nested. You must call the `require_relative` from your `Race` class. I edited it to explain above.